# How to get a startpoint, endpoint and distance of "boatFerry" segment in Here Routing API

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to get "boatFerry" segment (startpoint, endpoint, distance, etc.) from the calculated route response via Here Routing API. What parameters I should use in my request to get it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight attribute or field to get only the boatFerry segment details in a route. However, you can get this by using the below query where link information is provided.Every link has flags. You can search for the flag of your interest (in the below example search for railFerry) and sum their lengths.This will give you the ferry length in your route distance.Also, it provides you the start and end points.

```
https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=geo!stopOver!51.006511,2.321095&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!51.137062,0.911495&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy&representation=linkPaging&language=de-de&returnElevation=true&maneuverAttributes=position%2Clength%2CtravelTime%2CstartAngle&instructionFormat=text&routeAttributes=waypoints%2Csummary
```

Comment: In the context of the current issue, please, add -- how can I get "bridge" segment from Here Routing Api response?